# How can I change in JS a slider's value that has no id and was defined by JS and not HTML?

Tags: javascript, forms

The code is somewhere inside a big .js file. I tried two things.
I tried to check

```
document.forms
```

but it's empty.

Then I tried to use

```
document.querySelector('input[value=<value>]').value="x";
```

I got the error 436:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[value=]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) have a title that does not mention mucus (snot) and b) provides a [mre], showing how the input is added and how you're trying to get a reference to it later.